# Paste function to construct existing data frame name and evaluate in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a long list of data frames.

Here is a simple hypothetical example of a data frame:

```
DFrame<-data.frame(c(1,0),c("Yes","No"))

colnames(DFrame)<-c("ColOne","ColTwo")
```

I am trying to retrieve a specified column of the data frame using paste function.

```
get(paste("DFrame","$","ColTwo",sep=""))
```

The get function returns the following error, when trying to retrieve a specified column:

> Error in get(paste("DFrame", "$", "ColTwo", sep = "")) :object 'DFrame$ColTwo' not found

When I enter the constructed name of the data frame `DFrame$ColTwo` it returns the desired output of the second column.

If I reconstruct an example without the '$' sign then I get the desired answer from the get function. For example the code yields 2:

enter code here
    Ans <- 2

```
get(paste("An","s",sep=""))

[1] 2
```

I am looking for the same desired outcome, but struggling to get past the error that the object could not be found.

I also attempted using the following format, but the quotation in the column name breaks the paste function:

```
paste("DFrame","[,"ColTwo"]",sep="")
```

Thank you very much for the input,
Kind regards

Comment: it is not entirely clear to me why you would reference a column by a paste function

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the following syntax:

```
get("DFrame")[,"ColTwo"]
```

You can use paste() in both of these strings, for example:

```
get(paste("D", "Frame", sep=""))[,paste("Col", "Two", sep="")]
```

Edit: Despite someone downvoting this answer without leaving a comment, this does exactly what the original poster asked for. If you feel that it does not or is in some way dangerous, I would encourage you to leave a comment.

Comment: I have a list of eg. 100 data frames, where i want to do repetitive calculations, extracting elements from the data frames. (prefix of data frame will be different - eg. OneDFrame , TwoDFrame etc. 

Thus there will be 100 more or less identical data frames with the same columns and different data. I will be using a loop to go through all the data frames and do calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Stop trying to use `paste` and `get` entirely.

The whole point of having a list (of data frames, say) is that you can reference them using names:

```
DFrame<-data.frame(c(1,0),c("Yes","No")) 
colnames(DFrame)<-c("ColOne","ColTwo")

#A list of data frames
l <- list(DFrame,DFrame)

#The data frames in the list can have names
names(l) <- c("DF1",'DF2')

# Now you just use `[[`
> l[["DF1"]][["ColOne"]]
[1] 1 0
> l[["DF1"]][["ColTwo"]]
[1] Yes No 
Levels: No Yes
```

If you have to, you can use `paste` to construct the indices passed inside `[[`.

Comment: joran: I would appreciate you not downvoting my correct answer simply because you dislike what the original poster is trying to do.

Comment: @RobHall I would appreciate you not assuming that you know who down voted your question, when voting is entirely anonymous. (For the record, I don't like helping people use methods that will get them in trouble like `get`, but I didn't down vote.)

Comment: Presumably he needs to iterate over some data stored in an inconvenient way. paste() nested in some loops may well be the most efficient way to do that. A list might be more elegant, but you need to construct that list first. If you feel that paste() or get() are dangerous to use, please elaborate why.

Comment: @RobHall The first sentence of the question states that the OP is working with "a long list of data frames", implying that the list is already created. I'm don't think that rehashing a well-trodden topic on which there is a wide consensus in the R community (i.e. `get` and `assign` can be the right tools, but rarely, and one most commonly sees them being used unnecessarily by beginners) with you at this particular moment would be very productive.